# Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint .Problema MySQL

Tags: mysql

estoy teniendo un error en la creacion de una tabla , me esta saliendo el error de MySQL 1215

- Ya comprobe los tipos de datos
- El nombre es el mismo

La creacion de la tabla usuarios es la siguiente :

```html
create table if not exists usuarios ( -- listo
 idusuarios INT not null auto_increment,
    documento INT not null,
    nombre varchar(45),
    apellido varchar(45),
    email varchar(45),
    observaciones varchar(90),
    natalicio varchar(45),
    estado char(1),
    domicilio varchar(45),
    primary key (idusuarios,documento)
    )
engine=innodb;
```

La creacion de la tabla cargos es la siguiente:

```html
create table cargos(
 idCargos int not null auto_increment primary key,
    nombre varchar(30) not null,
    estado char(1),
    descripcion varchar(45),
    observaciones varchar(90) null default null
)engine=innodb;
```

Y la creacion de la tabla empleadosCargos es la siguiente:

```html
create table if not exists empleadosCargos(
 Documento INT not null,
    idCargos INT not null,
    idUsuarios int not null,
    foreign key (Documento,idUsuarios) references usuarios(documento,idusuarios),
    foreign key (idCargos) references cargos(idcargos)
)engine=InnoDB;
```

Esta es la imagen del error :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano . Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Realmente no se la causa del problema pero realice una prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
create table if not exists empleadosCargos( 
     Documento INT not null, 
     idCargos INT not null, 
     idUsuarios int not null, 
     foreign key (idUsuarios, Documento) references usuarios(idusuarios, documento), 
     foreign key (idCargos) references cargos(idcargos) 
)engine=InnoDB
```

Crea la tabla sin problemas,  por lo que intuyo que es el orden de las columnas estaba afectando la creación de la tabla ya que de siguiente manera no funciona:

```
foreign key (Documento,idUsuarios) references usuarios(documento,idusuarios)
```

Pero de la siguiente manera si crea la tabla:

```
foreign key (idUsuarios, Documento) references usuarios(idusuarios, documento)
```

Comment: Es correcto. En este caso se debe respetar el orden en que está declarada la restricción en la tabla padre, que este: `... primary key (idusuarios,documento)`

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias por la aclaración, este punto no lo sabia :)