# MySQL problema: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, constraints

Tengo dos **Foreigns Keys** y no logro que se inserten, me da error. Alguna idea:

```
mysql> create table Inscritos(
-> id int(6) not null auto_increment,
-> estudianteId int(6) unsigned not null,
-> tutorialId int(6) unsigned not null,
-> primary key(id),
-> index (estudianteId),
-> index (tutorialId),
-> foreign key(estudianteId) references Student(id),
-> foreign key(tutorialId) references Tutorials(id)
-> );
```

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

La creación de la tabla Student es la siguiente:

```
mysql> create table Student(
-> id int(6) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
-> firstname varchar(30) not null,
-> lastname varchar(30) not null
-> );
```

Y la creación de la tabla Tutorials es:

```
mysql> create table Tutorials(
-> id int(6) auto_increment primary key,
-> title varchar(100) not null,
-> author varchar(40) not null,
-> date DATE 
-> );
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y esas dos tablas, como estan definidas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18930154/3239070 puede servirte esa respuesta.

Comment: @MLStud aca en el sitio esta lleno tambien de respuestas sobre este tema. Pero mejor esperar ver que tienen las otras tablas para ver el problema especifico

Comment: Sería interesante ver la estructura, el engine y el charset de las otras dos tablas, alguna vez me paso que por tener diferente charset o por que los campos (origen, destino) no eran idénticos en tipo, no creaba los foreign.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint .Problema MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171844/error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-problema-mysql)

Comment: @CristhianMayuri ya añadí las otras dos tablas

Comment: @gbianchi alguna idea?,

Comment: trata de hacer los create tables al inicio y al final ejecutas los alter table con los foreign keys es la forma mas segura de hacerlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré el problema, en:
    tutorialId int(6) unsigned not null,
No debería ir el "unsigned".

Igual gracias a todos por sus comentarios.

Comment: Que bueno té sirvió, pero te comento que el unsigned si debería ir pues asegura no ingreses enteros negativos

Answer (score 2):

Para las foreign keys necesitas que los campos sean identicos, el problema que veo aquí es que en la tabla `Tutorials` el campo `id` es int(6) pero en `Inscritos` se define como tutorialId int(6) `unsigned` not null.

Prueba crear `Tutorials` con id `unsigned` al igual que en `Inscritos`

Saludos